# HTML5 Video Event Listeners not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I'm trying to add an 'ended' and 'timeupdate' event listener to my video player, but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
//File: watch.php
//Folder Layout:
//root
//   watch.php
//   js/
//      jquery-3.3.1.min.js
//      bootstrap.min.js
//   cs/
//      bootstrap.min.css
//      style.css

<html>

<head>
    <?php
    $video_link = "first_video.mp4";
    ?>

    <title>Watch Video</title>

    <!-- STYLESHEETS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <?php echo "<video id='video_player' src='$video_link' controls autoplay onclick='this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();' oncontextmenu='return false;'>Browser doesn't support HTML5 Video!</video>"; ?>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var video = document.getElementById('video_player');

        function Ended() 
        {
            alert("Ended!");
            $('#video_player').attr('src', 'second_video.mp4');
            video.load();
            video.play();
        };

        function TimeUpdate()
        {
            if(video.currentTime > (1 * 60))
                alert("1min passed...");
        };

        video.addEventListener('ended', Ended);
        video.addEventListener('timeupdate', TimeUpdate);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If somebody could explain to me why it doesn't work that would be great. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors. Need to remove the parenthesis after closing the TimeUpdate and Ended functions.

```
function Ended() 
    {
        alert("Ended!");
        video.source = "second_video.mp4";
        video.load();
        video.play();
    })<--- remove this;
```

Comment: Sorry an afterthought you need to change your jquery to make the second video load properly as well. should read more like.  $('#video_player').attr('src', 'second_video.mp4');

Comment: yes, i updated both things in my OP, but sadly it still doesn't work.

Comment: Well like Karl showed in the fiddle suggested code should work. I would be looking in the console for some kind of syntax error (f12 in chrome), also check and make sure your imports are pointing to right places for your css and javascript location. I know depending on the environment sometimes I have to prefix the locations with a ./ maybe something along those lines happening? if you can post what your console showing after changes maybe we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your Ended and TimeUpdate functions.

```
    function Ended() 
    {
        alert("Ended!");
        video.source = "second_video.mp4";
        video.load();
        video.play();
    };

    function TimeUpdate()
    {
        if(video.currentTime > (1 * 60))
            alert("1min passed...");
    };
```

Your original code contains an unnecessary closing bracket at the end of both functions. Codepen of the code working: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRWRyQ?editors=1111

Comment: Removed them and updated the OP, but it still doesn't work :/